# custom error from aws cognito trigger lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Is there a way to customize the error from cognito trigger lambda?

```
export async function handler(event: PreSignUpTriggerEvent, context: Context, callback: Callback<PreSignUpTriggerEvent>): Promise<void> {
    console.log(event);
    // Return to Amazon Cognito
    callback(message, event);            
}
```

This would return the following error to my callback url

```
http://localhost:3000/?error_description=PreSignUp+failed+with+error+Error%3A+User+not+exists+in+the+system.+Access+deny.+&error=invalid_request
```

I understand its not possible to change the `error_description` to remove the `PreSignUp+failed+with+error` prefix ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55195656/sending-message-from-cognito-triggers)).

However, is it possible to customize the `error=invalid_request` query param to `error=access_denied` or anything custom error other than `invalid_request`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this link as a base example and return a constant to identify the error on the client-side:

[image]

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-sign-up.html

Example:

```js
const error = new Error("EMAIL_MISSING");
callback(error, event);
```

**Update**

Like @srx said: the response of Cognito will be, via the query string, the error described by them plus your constant, like below:
`error_description=PreSignUp+failed+with+error+EMAIL_MISSING`

So you can check on the client-side. On the snippet of a react app bellow I did it:

```js
const locationSearch = String("error_description=PreSignUp+failed+with+error+EMAIL_MISSING");
const isAzureError = locationSearch.includes('AZURE_IDP_ERROR');
const isEmailMissing = locationSearch.includes('EMAIL_MISSING');
```

Comment: This will respond with `error_description=PreSignUp+failed+with+error+EMAIL_MISSING`

Comment: Exactly. On the client-side you can check if there is this constant on the `error_description`.

Comment: All we want to know is if there is a way to remove the prefix in `error_description` or have a custom error instead of `error=invalid_request`

Comment: This is more of a workaround which I already implemented. However, it is not great solution because it involves string parsing instead of using value of param. The prefix also depends on the trigger lambda type. There is no documentation specifying the format of the prefix, therefore it is at a risk of changing.

Comment: @srx, I didn't find a solution like that, so I did this workaround.

Comment: Honestly, the Cognito service is not very flexible in many ways, making the job a little more complicated.

Comment: Anyone have any workaround for the python part ! they only said to raise an Exception but client side will say invalid_response . No way to pass custom error message